# Помогите исправить баг в игре на tkinter (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Создал такую игру. Если нажимаешь на круг - добавляются очки, если на квадрат - отнимаются.
Хочу исправить баг, дело в том, что круг исчезает не сразу, и его можно "закликать" и получить больше очков чем нужно. Тоже самое и с квадратом. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы после нажатия круг/квадрат либо исчезали сразу, либо не прибавляли больше очков?

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Меню')
root.geometry('300x300+500+0')
count = 0
def click():
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry('+500+0')
    window.title('Шарики и квадраты')
    window.resizable(False, False)
    c = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 600, bg = 'white')
    p = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 100, bg = 'orange')
    z = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 30, bg = 'orange')

    z.create_text(280,15, font='Arial 18',text='Удачи! Набери 20 очков)')

colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow','green','blue']

def lose():
   window.destroy()
   global count
   count += 1
   win1 = Tk()
   win1.title('Вы проиграли!')
   win1.geometry('350x100+500+0')
   win1.resizable(False,False)
   label2= ttk.Label(win1,text='Вы проиграли! Ваш счёт ушел в минус :(')
   label2.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand = 1)
   win1.mainloop()
   
def win():
  window.destroy()
  global count
  count -= 20
  win2 = Tk()
  win2.title('Вы Выиграли!')
  win2.geometry('350x100+500+0')
  win2.resizable(False,False)
  label3= ttk.Label(win2,text='Вы выиграли! Ваш счёт равен 20')
  label3.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand = 1)
  win2.mainloop()
   

def click_on_circle(event):
     global count
     count += 1
     print(str(count))
     p.delete(ALL)
     p.create_text(80,30, font= "Arial 18",text="Попаданий: ")
     p.create_text(180,30, font= "Arial 20",text=str(count))
     
     if count == 20:
       win()
     else:
       pass

def click_on_rect(event):
  global count
  count -= 1
  print(str(count))
  p.delete(ALL)
  p.create_text(80,30, font= "Arial 18",text="Попаданий: ")
  p.create_text(180,30, font= "Arial 20",text=str(count))
  
  if count < 0:
     lose()
  else:
    pass
  
def funcs():
  if True :
   f = [ball, rect]
   rand_func = random.choice(f)
   rand_func()

def ball():
  c.delete(ALL)
  x = random.randint(10,580)
  y = random.randint(10,580)
  r = 30
  new_ball = c.create_oval (x, y, x+r, y+r, fill = random.choice(colors), width=0)
  c.tag_bind(new_ball, '<Button-1>',click_on_circle)
  window.after(1500,funcs)

def rect():
  c.delete(ALL)
  x = random.randint(10,580)
  y = random.randint(10,580)
  r = 30
  new_rect = c.create_rectangle (x, y, x+r, y+r, fill = random.choice(colors), width=0)
  c.tag_bind(new_rect, '<Button-1>',click_on_rect)
  window.after(1500,funcs)


funcs()        
c.pack()
p.pack()
z.pack()
window.mainloop()

label = ttk.Label(root, text='Привет! Правила игры: \n Попробуй поймать шары, но опасайся квадратов! \n Шар = +1 очко, Квадрат = -1 очко')
buton = ttk.Button(text='Играть',command=click)
buton.pack(anchor= CENTER, expand = 1)
label.pack(anchor=N,expand = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, трудность у вас?

Comment: А проблема в том, что в текущий момент, с помощью одно круга можно получить условно 5-6 очков, если быстро нажимать, а нужно чтобы было только один раз и затем он сразу пропадал, не давая возможности набрать больше очков , чем 1 за один объект

Comment: Избавьтесь от второго TK() в программе, используйте для открытия новых окон Toplevel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421508/can-you-have-two-instances-of-tkinter-in-python

Comment: Благодарю за замечание